# Ruby regex for international phone numbers while excluding a specific country code

Tags: regex, ruby

I'm trying to create a regex to authorize international phone numbers in a form, while excluding phone numbers from France (i.e. starting with "+33", since I created a specific regex for this case). 
This regex should catch phone numbers starting with '+' followed by the country code (1 to 4 digits) and 4 to 9 digits, with no space/dash/dot.

I've been looking around and came up with the following one, which includes all international phone numbers:

```rb
(\(?\+[1-9]{1,4}\)?([0-9]{4,11})?)
```

I want to exclude French numbers with...

```rb
[^+33]
```

but I can't find a way to combine it with my current regex.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This regex should catch phone numbers starting with '+' followed by the country code (1 to 4 digits) and 4 to 9 digits, with no space/dash/dot.

Use

```
\A(?!\+33)\+\d{1,3}\d{4,9}\z
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/FBiZqi/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    33                       '33'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \+                       '+'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d{4,9}                  digits (0-9) (between 4 and 9 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \z                       the end of the string
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast and detailed answer, it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Use a negative lookahead at the beginning

```
(?!^\+33)(\(?\+[1-9]{1,4}\)?([0-9]{4,11}) ?)
```

(?!^+33) True if not begin by +33

Comment: Thank you very much for your super quick answer and explanation about negative lookahead.